# Menu links only using http after enabling https, unable to redirect http links

Tags: redirect, htaccess, https, mod-rewrite

I have a WordPress website on a Bluehost shared hosting server and since I have multiple websites in my space, I have this particular folder in its own folder under `public_html`. This means that I have a `.htaccess` file in `public_html`, which redirects my domain to the specific website folder. I also have another `.htaccess` file in the website folder, which has some WordPress settings and a redirect for non-www URLs. I've tried adding this http -> https rule in both `.htaccess` files, but it has no effect:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm also having related issues with menu links in WordPress. Even though my WP and site addresses contain https, my menu links are rendering with http. This happens if I use a custom link with just the anchor ID or full URL. Could anything in the `.htaccess` file be interfering? Why would my http -> https rule be ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.me [NC]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.me/$1 [R,L]
> ```

You've not stated where exactly you are adding these rules in your `.htaccess` file(s). The order is important. These directives need to go at the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress front-controller, otherwise they won't redirect anything other than static resources.

This rule will also only redirect `example.com`, it won't canonicalise a request for `http://www.example.com/` (ie. HTTP and www) - which is presumably the intention.

To redirect non-www to www *and* HTTP to HTTPS you would need to include the `OR` flag in the first condition it's either `example.com` *or* HTTP - the default is otherwise an implicit *AND*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.me [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.me/$1 [R,L]
```

You also don't need the `<IfModule>` wrapper or to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive if it is already present later in the file.

Ultimately this should be a 301 (permanent) redirect, so change `R` to `R=301` once you have confirmed it works as intended.

> I have an `.htaccess` file in public_html, which **redirects** my domain to the specific website folder

I assume you do literally mean a "redirect" and not an internal rewrite? In which case this is OK. However, if you are internally rewriting the request to the specific subdirectory then the above is incorrect as it will expose the subdirectory in the URL. In this case you should remove the rule from the subdirectory `.htaccess` file.

Comment: This rule worked. Thank you so much! I placed it at the top of my website folder's .htaccess file. It now redirects non-www and http links correctly. The only remaining issue is that my WP menu is generating links with http.

Comment: Never mind, I was looking at the wrong menu. All good now